# Building a query in Doctine with quietly builder

Tags: php, symfony, orm, console, doctrine

I am trying to create this mysql query into query builder in Doctrine but having issues. Here is my mysql query

```
SELECT * FROM invoice i WHERE i.created_at >='2019-03-01 00:00:00';
```

Here is what I have so far for query builder. Can anyone spot what i am doing wrong?

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder('i');
$qb->select('*')
   ->from('invoice', 'i')
   ->where('i.create_at >=','2019-03-01 00:00:00');
$query = $this->$qb->getQuery();
$results = $this->$query->getResult();

$output->writeln($this->$results);
```

Comment: Why are you aliasing when there is no need to in your current query?

Comment: which part @Script47

Answer (score 0):

I spot a little typo.

`i.create_at -> i.created_at`

And Renan is right- no comma necessary in your where statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('i');
$qb->select('i')
    ->where($qb->expr()->gte('i.create_at',':date'))
    ->setParameter('date',new \DateTime('2019-03-01 
     00:00:00'));
 $results = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
 $output->writeln($results);
```

this how to write it in the repository,the point is no need to use from statement and instead of * you should  use the alias which is "i" here , and you should use expr in your where statement  but be sure the field created_at is  what you have in your entity and not database mapping (be sure in your entity it is created_at )

Answer (score -1):

I think that you has a error in the ->where function.

The correct is:

```
->where('i.create_at >= 2019-03-01 00:00:00');
```